# Why is my rails app calling the $(document).bind('ajaxError') function when the AJAX call actually creates a new Rails Object?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 modals to add new Objects to my Rails database. It works well for all the modals so far, but the latest one I've added is causing me a headache. The Modal does not dismiss, nor does the Create.js.erb code properly execute - as far as I can tell, one part of my code (designed to take any AJAX errors and parse the JSON into the error fields on the modal) is in fact executing the create.js.erb code instead.

My Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @sale_contact.save
     puts 'if statement'
    format.html { redirect_to @sale_contact.sales_opportunity, notice: 'Sale contact was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sale_contact }
    format.js 
  else
    puts 'else statement'
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @sale_contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render json: @sale_contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Results in the "if statement" being invoked - and the Terminal response:

```
Rendered sale_contacts/_table.html.erb (29.8ms)
Rendered sale_contacts/create.js.erb (32.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 32.5ms | ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
```

This is truncated, but I can see the object takes the correct parameters, inserts them into the database and then attempts to load my create.js.erb file.

The console returns an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c
jQuery.parseJSON @ jquery.js body=1:8483
(anonymous function) @ organizations.js?body=1:13
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js body=1:4642
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery.js body=1:4310
jQuery.event.trigger @ jquery.js?body=1:4551
done @ jquery.js?body=1:9286
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback @ jquery.js?body=1:9686
```

The anonymous function is not targeted at this modal, but fires nontheless:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).bind('ajaxError', 'form#new_user', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){

// note: jqxhr.responseJSON undefined, parsing responseText instead
console.log(jqxhr.responseText)
$(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) );
 });
});
```

The log of the jqxhr.responseText to my console shows that the responseText is in fact my create.js.erb file for the sale_contact:

```
    console.log('anything at all');
//update the selection list with the new sale contact, and close the modal
$('#sales_opp_sale_contact_modal').modal('hide')
                    .clear_previous_errors();
resetForm($('#new_sale_contact'));
$input = $('#contact_error');
$input.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.warning-block').html('');
//render the newly added sale contact to the table if the AJAX call succeeded
console.log('fired');
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler. The ajax response was: " +
  xhr.responseText );
    $('#sales-opp-key-contacts-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'sale_contacts/table')%>");
    //console.log(document);
    $('.alert').remove();
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#sale-contacts').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
});
```

I have literally copied and pasted the exact same code (with differing model names and DOM targets) for all the other modals I'm using, all of which work successfully. Upon reloading the page, the Rails object (a SaleContact) is in the table, as I expect it to be.

Why is the ajaxERROR code firing, and why is it trying to parse the create.js.erb file in this case? How can I get this behaviour to stop?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So, I've isolated the fact that ajaxError is being fired, even though the server returns a 200 OK status. This then causes the Sale_Contact controller to pass the create.js.erb file to the AJAX event handler, which leads to the error above.

I added the following to try and understand what was going on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('ajaxError', function(req, err){ 
   console.log('my message' + err);
 });
});
```

Which returns:

```
my message[object Object]
```

In the console. I thought it might be my routes, so I updated the routes.rb:

```
  resources :sales_opportunities do
   resources :timeline_events, shallow: true
   resources :swots, shallow: true
   resources :sale_contacts, shallow: true
  end
```

this has also had no impact.

Can anyone suggest a method to debug the AJAX/Rails app so I can understand why AJAX thinks an Error has occurred even though Rails says the status is 200 OK? (I presume the Bootstrap Modal is also not closing as it's relying on another AJAX call being successful to close).

Comment: Does it work correctly if you comment this line: $(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) );

Comment: No - it stops the error from showing in the console, but the modal remains open on the page and the create.js.erb code does not run (it doesn't re-load the partial with the sale_contact table in). When I reload the page, the sale_contact is present in the sale_contacts table though - and the terminal still says that it has rendered both the table and the js.